# is it the right way to attach the function to each element

Tags: javascript, dom

Is it the right way to atach the function to each element ? And is my function ok?

```
<ul id='forShopping'>
                    <li><input class='ch' type='checkbox' onclick='isActive()'> Air-freshener</input></li>
                    <li><input class='ch' type='checkbox' onclick='isActive()'> Pampers</input></li>
                    <li><input class='ch' type='checkbox' onclick='isActive()'> Newspapper</input></li>
                    <li><input class='ch' type='checkbox' onclick='isActive()'> Toilet paper</input></li>
</ul>

function isActive () {
    let elem = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(let i=0; i<elem.length; i++){
        if(elem[i].checked == true){
            elem[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'forestGreen';
        }else{
            elem[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        }
    }
}
```

It works this way but i`m not sure it is properly.

Comment: use `this` and will refer to current element . so need to use for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though your code will work , but still it will be a costly process, since on every click it have to get element from with specific tag from DOM, & will loop through it. Instead pass the context of this with the function.

hope this snippet will be useful

**JS**

```
function isActive(elem) {
 if (elem.checked == true) {
    elem.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'forestGreen';
  } else {
    elem.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id='forShopping'>
  <li>
    <input class='ch' type='checkbox' onclick='isActive(this)'> Air-freshener></li>
  <li>
    <input class='ch' type='checkbox' onclick='isActive(this)'> Pampers></li>
  <li>
    <input class='ch' type='checkbox' onclick='isActive(this)'> Newspapper></li>
  <li>
    <input class='ch' type='checkbox' onclick='isActive(this)'> Toilet paper></li>
</ul>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/swx7eust/)

Comment: Sure it is! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function isActive (a) {
        if(a.checked == true)
         a.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'forestGreen';
        else
           a.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
}
```

```html
<ul id='forShopping'>
                    <li><input class='ch' type='checkbox' onclick='isActive(this)'> Air-freshener</input></li>
                    <li><input class='ch' type='checkbox' onclick='isActive(this)'> Pampers</input></li>
                    <li><input class='ch' type='checkbox' onclick='isActive(this)'> Newspapper</input></li>
                    <li><input class='ch' type='checkbox' onclick='isActive(this)'> Toilet paper</input></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css pseudo class `:checked` (no need of js for this).

Example snippet

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
}
.ch:checked + label {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul id='forShopping'>
  <li>
    <input class='ch' type='checkbox' />
    <label>Air-freshener</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class='ch' type='checkbox'>
    <label>Pampers</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class='ch' type='checkbox'>
    <label>Newspapper</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class='ch' type='checkbox'>
    <label>Toilet paper</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this is an better answer but it should highlight the entire li